# What is the Alernative for MODE_WORLD_READABLE in android?

Tags: android, android-file

I am trying to write some images in android internal memory if there is no external memory.

```
    File sdDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "mydir");
    File filesysDir = getDir("mydir", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    File file = new File(sdDir, "myfile.txt");
```

So i have written above code but MODE_WORLD_READABLE is not available now; so what are the different way by which i can write the file and access it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);

File directory = cw.getDir("mydir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: @Rahul check my edit and let me know if it works. You may need to remove the filesysdir line

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Android reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE), the constant is deprecated from API 17.
As said in the document, the constant still work but the permission may not be keeped after a backup of your app.

This is for files private to your app BUT as your create the file into external storage, the permission has no sense since other app with right permission can read it.

To allow read of private files, Android documentation suggests to create a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#openFile%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%29) proposing files management for a while.